# Multiple attachments creation in single email apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, singleemailmessage

I have to create multiple attachments in a single email method. Below is my email class. Can someone help me?

**Apex Class**

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='+formquantity);
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
       // return pageRef;
       system.debug('@@Saikat1'+email);  

// Take the PDF content
Blob b = pageRef.getContent();
// Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b);

   List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 
      // activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()];
       for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     
            addresses.add( u.Email);
            addresses.add('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');
            }
//or can do this addresses.add( userinfo.getuserEmail()); don't need any soql
            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
            email.setToAddresses( addresses );
            email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');
            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
            system.debug('@@Saikat'+email);
            // Sends the email

                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can create multiple attachment same as single attachment. check @Ratan Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple attachments and pass into method.

```
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
efa.setBody(b);
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa1.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
efa1.setBody(b);
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa, efa1 });
```

---

### Updates

```
List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> lstFileAttachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();

for(integer i = 0; i <5; i++)
{
   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
   efa.setBody(b);
   lstFileAttachments.add(efa);
}
email.setFileAttachments(lstFileAttachments);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need variable number of attachments , may be any number of pdfs. It depends on an integer variable say counter. Please suggest me.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner check my updated ans.

Comment: Thanks Ratan for your code , this is awesome and would be very helpful to me.